# How to get quantitiy from table stock_available in Prestashop 1.7.6

Tags: php, sql, prestashop

Please help.
How and where to create this custom SQL query:
get '**quantity**' from table '**ps_stock_available**'

I need to replace the existing variable '$product.quantity' in page:
/themes/my_theme_name/templates/catalog/_partials/product-add-to-cart.tpl

```
{block name='product_availability'}
 <span id="product-availability">
    {if $product.show_availability && $product.availability_message}
      {if $product.availability == 'available'}
        <i class="material-icons rtl-no-flip product-available">&#xE5CA;</i> {$product.availability_message}</span> <span data-stock="{$product.quantity}" data-allow-oosp="{$product.allow_oosp}">{$product.quantity} {$product.quantity_label}</span>
      {elseif $product.availability == 'last_remaining_items'}
        <i class="material-icons product-last-items">&#xE002;</i> {$product.availability_message}</span> <span data-stock="{$product.quantity}" data-allow-oosp="{$product.allow_oosp}">{$product.quantity} {$product.quantity_label}</span>
      {else}
        <i class="material-icons product-unavailable">&#xE14B;</i> {$product.availability_message}</span>
      {/if}
    {/if}
{/block}
```

The reason is that if the customer adds the last piece to the cart, it will appear on the product detail and product list as Out of stock. That's not good.

Please advise?
Thank you

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Hi Sfili_81 - I edited the ask. Thank You